# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dataclasses'

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to use in windows 10, tensorflow-gpu 2.4.0 to object detection. I don't know how to fix this error, could you please help me?

```
(tensorflow1) C:\tensorflow1\models\research\object_detection>python train.py --logtostderr --train_dir=training/ --pipeline_config_path=training/faster_rcnn_inception_v2_pets.config
2021-01-06 17:59:49.219069: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 53, in <module>
    from object_detection.builders import model_builder
  File "C:\tensorflow1\models\research\object_detection\builders\model_builder.py", line 66, in <module>
    from object_detection.models import ssd_efficientnet_bifpn_feature_extractor as ssd_efficientnet_bifpn
  File "C:\tensorflow1\models\research\object_detection\models\ssd_efficientnet_bifpn_feature_extractor.py", line 33, in <module>
    from official.vision.image_classification.efficientnet import efficientnet_model
  File "C:\tensorflow1\models\official\vision\image_classification\efficientnet\efficientnet_model.py", line 32, in <module>
    from dataclasses import dataclass
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dataclasses'
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: After many hours, I found the solution! I Use pip uninstall dataclasses and later, pip install dataclasses!

Answer (score 2):

Dataclasses (https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) were introduced in Python 3.7. Based on the error message you posted, I conclude that you are not using a version of Python 3.7 or later. The docs officially state that you need Python 3.5–3.8 (https://www.tensorflow.org/install), so don't use 3.9 which would be the latest version. But actually, the files you are using require dataclasses, and so require 3.7 or higher. I recommend upgrading to Python 3.8 to maximize your compatibility.

Comment: As a side note, do not use tensorflow1 (which is deprecated), use tensorflow2. With tensorflow2, there is no tensorflow-gpu package, just tensorflow, and it can handle gpu as long as you have the proper cuda stuff installed.

Comment: Yes, I will use tensorflow2, but I'm trying to solve one problem with checkpoints in  model_main_tf2.py. I will ask another question on stackoverflow :((